# Combining results

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

[image: Query shows results like:]

I need results to be shown in one row instead of few.

Query:

```
SELECT C.ClientCaseNumber,
            C.SetId,
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (28, 29, 30) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Wezwania],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (14, 21) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Kontakt],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 32 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [SMS],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 44 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Zgon],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 49 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Areszt],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 37 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Odmowa],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 39 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Podważa],
           Sum(CASE
                 WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 99 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) AS [Ugoda],
           [Adres],
           [Info1],
           [Numer],
           [Info2],
           [Mail],
           [Info3],
           [Powód]
    FROM   (SELECT cast(Notes as char) AS [Adres], CaseActionDefinitionId AS [Info1], NULL AS [Numer], NULL as [Info2], NULL AS [Mail], NULL as [Info3], NULL AS [Powód], CaseDetailId
            FROM   CaseActionHistory
            WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, cast(Info as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, NULL, NULL, CaseDetailId
            FROM   CaseActionHistory
            WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                          59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
        UNION ALL
            SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Notes as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, CaseDetailId
            FROM   CaseActionHistory
            WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
        UNION ALL
            SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Description as char(100)), CaseDetailId
            FROM   CaseActionDefinition JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
            WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
           INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
                   ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
           INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
                   ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
    WHERE  C.ClientId = 11
    GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber, [Adres], [Numer], [Mail], [Info1], [Powód], [Info2], [Info3], C.SetId
```

I suppose I need to get rid somehow of few things in GROUP BY however I don't really have an idea how to change the query itself to make thing work correctly.

Comment: Can you show us the designer view for the report? This query is too big for me to look into atm, but you should be able to group in the report itself on f.ex ClientCaseNumber.

Comment: Designer view of report is nothing more than just a table with inserted columns. I do not want to group by ClientCaseNumber. I need to combine those 3 rows into 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should declare table and insert into it: SetId and all SUM(...) and group by SetId. Then update table with other data.

Sample:

```
declare @table table (
ClientCaseNumber int
,SetId int
,Wezwania int
,Kontakt int
,SMS int
,Zgon int
,Areszt int
,Odmowa int
,Podważa int
,Ugoda int
,Adres nvarchar(255)
,Info1 nvarchar(255)
,Numer nvarchar(255)
,Info2 nvarchar(255)
,Mail nvarchar(255)
,Info3 nvarchar(255)
,Powód nvarchar(255))

insert into @table (
ClientCaseNumber
,Wezwania
,Kontakt
,SMS
,Zgon
,Areszt
,Odmowa
,Podważa
,Ugoda)
SELECT
C.ClientCaseNumber,
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (28, 29, 30) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Wezwania],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (14, 21) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Kontakt],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 32 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [SMS],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 44 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Zgon],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 49 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Areszt],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 37 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Odmowa],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 39 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Podważa],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 99 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Ugoda]
FROM   (SELECT cast(Notes as char) AS [Adres], CaseActionDefinitionId AS [Info1], NULL AS [Numer], NULL as      [Info2], NULL AS [Mail], NULL as [Info3], NULL AS [Powód], CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, cast(Info as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, NULL, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                      59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Notes as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Description as char(100)), CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionDefinition JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
        WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
       INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
               ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
       INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
               ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
WHERE  C.ClientId = 11
GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber

update @table
set SetId = X.SetId
, Adres = X.Adres
,Info1 = X.Info1
,Numer = X.Numer
,Info2 = X.Info2
,Mail = X.Mail
,Info3 = X.Info3
,Powód = X.Powód
from
@table as T
join (
SELECT
    C.ClientId,
    C.SetId,
    [Adres],
    [Info1],
    [Numer],
    [Info2],
    [Mail],
    [Info3],
    [Powód]
FROM   (SELECT cast(Notes as char) AS [Adres], CaseActionDefinitionId AS [Info1], NULL AS [Numer], NULL as [Info2], NULL AS [Mail], NULL as [Info3], NULL AS [Powód], CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, cast(Info as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, NULL, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                      59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Notes as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Description as char(100)), CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionDefinition JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
        WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
       INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
               ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
       INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
               ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
    WHERE
        X.ClientId = 11
) as X on X.ClientCaseNumber = T.ClientCaseNumber

SELECT DISTINCT ClientCaseNumber,
            SetId,
           [Wezwania],
           [Kontakt],
           [SMS],
           [Zgon],
           [Areszt],
           [Odmowa],
           [Podważa],
           [Ugoda],
           [Adres],
           [Info1],
           [Numer],
           [Info2],
           [Mail],
           [Info3],
           [Powód]
    FROM  @table
```

Comment: And after make another SELECT with data I need? Cause puting above into Report Builder doesn't give me any type of fields to work with

Comment: Then select all results from that table.

Sample:

select
 ClientCaseNumber
 ,SetId
 ,Wezwania
 ,Kontakt
 ,SMS
 ,Zgon
 ,Areszt
 ,Odmowa
 ,Podważa
 ,Ugoda
 ,Adres
 ,Info1
 ,Numer
 ,Info2
 ,Mail
 ,Info3
 ,Powód
from
 @table

Comment: Since I needed grouping by ClientCaseNumber not SetId I replaced them in the table. http://pastebin.com/PdYGT1Z9 - current look of query. Shows same [Numer] [Mail], [Adres], [Powód] for all results.

Comment: If I understand correctly, now you have the code, which you wanted?

Comment: Nope. The last 4 columns of img above (1st post) shows same value for every ClientCaseNumber.

Comment: I update the code above. The problem was on update statement.
The where (WHERE X.ClientId = 11) clause must be above (as X)

Comment: Same stuff unfortunately.

Comment: The last try, if it doesn't help, then I coudn't help :(